# This didn't match minimum standards. Why? It seems valid to me

Tags: support

This question didn't seem to match the minimum standards to allow posting it. Could someone explain why that is the case?

> Hi i cant figure out how to get a c# Regex IsMatch to match a regular
>   expression followed by end of line or whitespace
>
> i currently have [\s]+keyword[\s]+ which works for space, but does not
>   work for keyword or keyword.
>
> i have tried [\s^]+keyword[\s$]+ but this makes it fail to match with
>   the spaces, and doesnt work on the end / start of string.
>
> heres the corde i tried
>
> string pattern = string.Format("[\s^]+{0}[\s$]+",keyword);
>   if(Regex.IsMatch(Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
>
> can anyone put me right please?

Comment: Wait wait wait wait wait wait wait wait wait wait...did you just ask us why that question is not accepted...or did you just ask as a C# RegEx question?

Comment: Lower case `i`? That's not correct English. Use `I` when referring to yourself.

Comment: Also, you should use more of those `'`and those `____` (these are four spaces, see code formattting).

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - The title suggests that the OP is asking why the posted question didn't meet minimum standards. A valid question for Meta, though not very clear.

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, that got me right there confused...I think the question is ambiguous at the moment and could mean both.

Comment: There @SulfurizedDemonbobby, no more confusion. ;)

Comment: @Bart: You cheated! ;)

Comment: Interesting, [you managed to post it anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213169/what-is-a-regular-expression-that-will-match-keyword-with-whitespace-of-end-st).

Comment: the title is the question and the rest is what i tried to add to the programming part of the website.
And i have looked at the quality standards and didnt understand why this post wasnt added, which is ahy i posted it here? for help in identifying what is wrong with it, not sniddy remarks!!!
i think that was a perfectly valid technical question and your standards stopped it being added, so i think they need revising, but he im obviously wrong.

Comment: p.s. dont think the -8 is fair, nor the duplicate tags as its not a duplicate as its an exact question on the contents included and if there is a duplicate that exactly matches this ill be amazed!!!

Comment: I don't understand why I get -11 for asking what I have done wrong with my other post not meeting QS and ask want I can do to improve my post as I thought it was a perfectly valid technical question, I don't think that should be punished, which is what i feel has happened here.

Answer (score 14):

Okay, let's go through it line by line, shall we?

> Hi.

[Taglines, salutations and signatures are not welcome on Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). They only clutter up the questions and answers and are completely unnecessary.

> i cant figure out how to get a c# Regex IsMatch to match a regular expression followed by end of line or whitespace

The English language uses and uppercase `I` for references to one self. That's because it is not a letter, but rather a whole word. Additionally, [contracted words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29) use an apostrophe `'` to signal that, f.e. it's not `dont` but `don't`.

> i have tried [\s^]+keyword[\s$]+ but this makes it fail to match with the spaces, and doesnt work on the end / start of string.

Inlined code should be formatted with accents "`", which allows you display that something is code. Accents should only be used for code, highlighting other words with them is most of the time not valid.

> heres the corde i tried

There's a [punctuation which is called a "colon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29), it is used to start quotes, further explanations or lists. This line should end with a colon.

> string pattern = string.Format("[\s^]+{0}[\s$]+",keyword); if(Regex.IsMatch(Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))

[Codeblocks need to be formated with four leading spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), otherwise they will be hard to read and no syntax highlighting will be applied.

> can anyone put me right please?

I sure tried!

Additionally, all of this what I just explained to you, [could you](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) [have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) [on your](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) [own](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) with a little effort.

Comment: thanks very much for your effort in highlighting the errors in that post, I will stop saying hi and stuff like that, and try to use proper english, thought my english is not that good as i have dyslexia.
I was posting on the technical forum so didnt think i would be quized on my proper use of english.

Comment: @f1wade: Because of the volume of SO we must enforce certain quality rules. Of course is this a technical *site* (not a forum, big difference) but without these rules in place Stack Exchange would decay to be another Yahoo! Answers or Experts Exchange. We take great pride in our enforcement of basic rules, which proper English is part of. Nearly all modern browsers support dictionaries and automatic correction, I suggest you start using those.